# Upgrade MacBook Air from OS X El Capitan to Mojave

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, macos-mojave

[image]

My mac specifications are on the photo above .. I'm afraid about upgrading my mac from El Capitan to Mojave and I'm asking :

1. am I going to lose my installed software?
2. am I going to lose my data ?
3. Will Mojave works in my machine as well as El Capitan or the system will become slow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. No
3. It's difficult to say with certainty, but if your system meets the specs listed [on Apple's upgrade page](https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/#hardware-requirements) then it will most likely perform as well as it does on El Capitan.

Make sure that you've done a full time machine backup of your system before doing the upgrade.